# Access to SQL Query Conversion containing FIRST()

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, ms-access

I am converting an MS Access query to a SQL Server stored procedure. I get to this point:

```
SELECT 
    AuthNum, AuthStatus, DateCreated, 
    MIN(DateInitiated) AS DateInitiated, 
    EventClassification, 
    FIRST(PlaceOfService) AS PlaceOfService, 
    Lob, MemId, 
    MAX(NoticeDate) AS NoticeDate, 
    MAX(Tat) AS Tat, 
    FIRST(StaffId) AS StaffId
FROM 
    PA_TAT_Detailed
GROUP BY 
    AuthNum, AuthStatus, DateCreated, EventClassification, Lob, MemId
HAVING
    ((FIRST(PlaceOfService) <> 'Inpatient Hospital') 
     AND (FIRST(PlaceOfService) <> 'Office - Dental') 
     AND (FIRST(PlaceOfService) <> 'Dialysis Center'))
    AND 
    ((MAX(Tat) Is Null) OR ((MAX(Tat) >= 0) AND (MAX(Tat) <= 28)))
ORDER BY 
    AuthNum;
```

But I don't know how to converted the `FIRST` operator. Any thoughts? Do I need to add an `ORDER BY` associated with the `GROUP BY` so I can `TAKE 1` perhaps?

Does `MIN` give the same result in this case?

BTW PlaceOfService, StaffId are strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should be pretty close. Double check that this returns the right info.

```
SELECT top 1 AuthNum
    , AuthStatus
    , DateCreated
    , MIN(DateInitiated) AS DateInitiated
    , EventClassification
    , PlaceOfService
    , Lob
    , MemId
    , MAX(NoticeDate) AS NoticeDate
    , MAX(Tat) AS Tat
    , StaffId
FROM PA_TAT_Detailed
where PlaceOfService not in ('Inpatient Hospital', 'Office - Dental', 'Dialysis Center')
GROUP BY AuthNum
    , AuthStatus
    , DateCreated
    , EventClassification
    , PlaceOfService
    , Lob
    , MemId
    , StaffId
HAVING MAX(Tat) Is Null 
    OR (MAX(Tat) >= 0 AND MAX(Tat) <= 28)
ORDER BY AuthNum;
```